# Install Sitecore 8.1 and 8.2 site side by side

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8

Is it possible to install a Sitecore 8.1 and Sitecore 8.2 site side-by-side ?  I have two different projects I am working on and I was wondering if I can have both on the same machine.

Comment: It's same like with Sitecore 7 and 8. Yes they can. Read more here:  https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/questions/6298/can-v7-and-v8-coexist-on-the-same-server

Comment: You just need to make sure you have the required .net versions for all the Sitecore versions you want to support. https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/087164

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, and the versions aren't relevant for this particular scenario. You can have as many separate instances of Sitecore as your hardware can support. Each Sitecore instance will be it's own Site in IIS with its own app pool, databases and application code.

I would suggest using the [Sitecore Instance Manager](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitecore_Instance_Manager.aspx). It makes spinning up new sitecore instances extremely easy.